# large permutation question

Tags: probability, permutations

What are the permutations of the following:
7 marbles each of 4 colors, for a total of 28 marbles.
A 5x5 board, so 25 places for 1 marble to be placed.
What are the permutations of placing the 25 marbles?

I don't think it is as straightforward as 28!/3!, but I'm unsure how to calculate this number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number $25$ can be "split up" in $4$ numbers $\leq7$ as follows:

$25=4+7+7+7$ giving $4$ possibilities when order is taken into account.

$25=5+6+7+7$ giving $12$ possibilities when order is taken into account.

$25=6+6+6+7$ giving $4$ possibilities when order is taken into account.

Presuming that all places on the board are distinguishable the number of placings is:

$$4\times\frac{25!}{4!7!7!7!}+12\times\frac{25!}{5!6!7!7!}+4\times\frac{25!}{6!6!6!7!}$$

Comment: Clear and straightforward explanation. Many thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome.